# What is best Eclipse plugin for AWT development?

Tags: windows, eclipse, plugins, awt

I want to use Eclipse and AWT to leverage the MS Windows heavy-weight UI components.  I need to develop a power-user UI in a hurry.  I am comfy with Eclipse.  Can anybody suggest plugins that will outperform or at least rival the development power of Developer Studio while providing access to a broad set of UI components available in Windows?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWT isn't the way to go. It will not provide you with access to many of the more complex Windows controls. The set of controls available in AWT is based on what is available natively across all platforms that Java supports, which isn't a very rich set. There hasn't been much development on AWT for a very long time. You should consider it a deprecated framework.

For desktop app development in Java, there are two prominent frameworks: Swing and SWT. Swing controls are rendered in Java (not native). SWT controls are native where available and rendered where not available.

[SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)

For a form builder editor plugin, see [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/).

Comment: Perfect, many thanks.  What's amazing is, I first saw your name 10 minutes before you posted while installing Sapphire 0.5.3.  But WindowBuilder seems to be closer to what I need.  I'd love to know how you went from submitting Sapphire to recommending WindowBuilder!

Comment: It all depends on what you need to do. Sapphire and WindowBuilder are drastically different approaches. If you want to tweak every single parameter of UI when constructing your form, then you would write SWT code by hand or by using a tool like WindowBuilder. If you are willing to give up some control, a framework like Sapphire will produce a highly-functional UI for several orders of magnitude less effort (even compared to using WindowBuilder). Sapphire sweet spot is with very large forms or large collections of forms, when you cannot afford to spend on a lot of time on any one field.